# How to open log with DEBUG level for tensorflow c++ core, not python client

Tags: tensorflow

I want to see the debug info for tensorflow c++ core, not python client. TensorFlow config INFO level default. How to modify the level to DEBUG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two types of logging. The INFO/WARNING/etc. logging statements are displayed by default. VLOG(n) statements are only displayed for n=0 by default. For more verbose logging, there is an environmental variable:

```
export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=2
```

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/6375 for details.

This gets you gorgeous messages such as:

```
2017-07-07 14:26:43.712063: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1557] Process node: 3 step 1 _retval_Const_0_0 = _Retval[T=DT_INT32, index=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const) is dead: 0
2017-07-07 14:26:43.712074: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:2345] Delete frame
```

Comment: `TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL` has been renamed to `TF_CPP_MAX_VLOG_LEVEL`.
Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/b64594d80ae2cfdba1c931c1df5db16d7f0c9e66#diff-2b1b69303b927a484e02c7fad9fc87d0d3ff0dc22ae1da0ecd0dc935d922a23cR229